# Implementing Strategy pattern with Reflection

Tags: java, class, reflection, classnotfoundexception, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to implement the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) using reflection, i.e. instantiate a new Concrete Strategy object using it's class name.

I want to have a configurable file with the class name in it. We have a database manager that will make changes available during run-time. Here's what I have so far:

```
StrategyInterface intrf = null;
try {
    String className = (String)table.get(someId);
    intrf = (StrategyInterface) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
return intrf;
```

I have a Class `ConcreteStrategy` which implements `StrategyInterface`. I have a test running in whcih `table.get(someID)` returns the `String "ConcreteStrategy"`.

My problem is that `ClassNotFoundEception` is thrown. Why is this happening, and how I could get `ConcreteStrategy` to be instantiated given a class name? I don't want to use an `if-else` block because number of concrete strategy objects will increase with time and development.

EDIT: I fixed it the following way,

```
String className = (String)table.get(custId);
className = TrackingLimiter.class.getPackage().getName() + "." + className;
limiter = (TrackingLimiter) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

Comment: Is the ConcreteStrategy included on your classpath? Are you using the FQN (package + name) of the class in your forName() call?

Comment: Post how you populate the 'table' strategy map.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was under the impression it would automatically add the package name. But adding the package name worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't forget package name and class ConcreteStrategy is available for classloader?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that classname you provide to forName() is fully qualified and correct.

`ClassNotFoundException` means exactly that.

So you need to ensure that the `ConcreteStrategy.class` (or a jar file containing it) is in class path.

In case new classes are made available really dynamically, i.e. you know that when YOUR program started, `ConcreteStrategy.class` did not exist, but a few hours/days later someone implemented it and put the fully qualified class name in the DB table, then along with the class name you also need the resource name (path of `ConcreteStrategy.class` (or a jar file containing it)).

Once you have both, you can use URLClassLoader to create an instance of ConcreteStrategy from `ConcreteStrategy.class` file or `jar_with_ConcreteStrategy_class.jar`.

[URLClassLoader example.](http://www.google.com/search?q=URLClassLoader%20example)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful, will keep in mind for future, when things starts to get serious.